# ARToolKit5+VS2017,use the source example,then link error2019 and 2001

Tags: artoolkit

I configure the `ARToolKit5` right in win10,and then I start a project by the `ARToolKit5` source example.
I include all the headers and libraries it used,and input the dynamic libraries . It still produce  link error 2019 and link error 2001.
I try a lot use the other methods,but still the same result!

**Error:**

[image: This is the error image,Debug,X86]

Please tell me how to solve,thanks a lot!

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: You could go with artoolkitX either from the prebuild: http://www.artoolkitx.org/docs/downloads/

Or from GitHub: https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx

artoolkitX should work on VS2017